# Python OCR Bitmap Numbers

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have the exact issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566319/tesseract-ocr-reading-a-low-resolution-pixelated-font-esp-digits) and the sample bitmap numbers even seem to look exactly the same; however, the solution no longer works as I get the error `AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'text'` on

```
tesser = cv2.text.OCRTesseract_create('C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/','eng','0123456789',3,3)
```

I'm using OpenCV 4.7.0 installed using `opencv-contrib-python`, pytesseract 0.3.10, and Tesseract 4 on Windows 10.

I believe the solution above no longer works with OpenCV 4.7.0.

Below is my script, but I get the result `511235160` rather than `0960051123160`.

Note that the numbers used to be vertical, and I have a script that extracts the numbers and lays them out horizontally, so spacing between numbers can be modified.

I appreciate any help on this as I've spent many hours trying to get it to work.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img_orig = cv2.imread('img_bitmap_numbers.png',0) # Load image as gray scale 

#Dilate (bloat) image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_orig, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
img_eroded = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel,iterations = 1)

# cv2.imshow('combined', img_eroded)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

tesseract_config = '--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'
a = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_eroded, lang='eng', config = tesseract_config)
print(a)
```

[image: bitmap numbers]

Comment: Changing iterations = 2 I get a better, but not a correct result: 90051123160.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her is my try:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

image_file = "numbers.png"

# load the input image, convert it from BGR to RGB channel ordering,
image = cv2.imread(image_file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print('Original Dimensions : ',image.shape)
 
scale_percent = 27 # percent of original size
width = int(rgb.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(rgb.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
  
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(rgb, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
print('Resized Dimensions : ',resized.shape)

grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 150, 245, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) # 0...255
bw = cv2.imshow('Black white image', blackAndWhiteImage)

# Configuration
options = r'--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.,:mIndexMtr'

# OCR the input image using Tesseract
text_bw = pytesseract.image_to_string(blackAndWhiteImage, config=options)
print(text_bw)

with open("numbers.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(text_bw)

cv2.imshow('Resized', resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:
**0960051123160**

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm getting the same result!
I'll incorporate this into my fuller script that extracts directly from a list of PDF files, but I'm very hopefull that it'll work for all other combinations of numbers! I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help!